# How to find out whether an assignment operator of T in a function template throws an exception?

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

Here is my function template:

```
template <typename T>
void f(vector<T> &a) noexcept(noexcept( /* ??? */ ))
```

I want to specify this function will not throw an exception given that the assignment operator `=` of `T` has `noexcept` specification. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @RSahu In libc++ I find the following code: `void swap(vector<T,Allocator>& x, vector<T,Allocator>& y)
    noexcept(noexcept(x.swap(y)));`. I think it's possible to make an instance of function template `noexcept` as long as the condition is known at compile-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with this:

```
template<typename T> 
void f(std::vector<T>& a) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable<T>::value)
{...}
```

It places a condition on the `noexcept` if copy-assigning `T` values is itself declared `noexcept`. You can further this into also taking account move-assigning `T`.

Comment: Nice answer. `noexcept(T()=T())`

Comment: @ZhengLuo: That assumes that `T` is default constructible... Better to use `std::declval`.